# How to delete a template?

Tags: c++, templates, delete-operator

I'm having trouble with deleting my template.
My template and destructor:

```
template<class S, class T>  
class Consortium
{

private :

    map<const S, Node<T>*> m_consortiumMap;
    Heap<T>m_consortiumHeap;

public :

    ~Consortium();
    void Insert(const S key, T toAdd);
    void Update(const S key);
    void Remove(const S key);
    const T Top();
};

template<class S, class T>
Consortium<S,T>::~Consortium()
{
    m_consortiumMap.clear();
    delete &m_consortiumHeap.;
}
```

My heap and destructor:

```
template <class T>
class Heap
{
private :

    vector<Node<T>*> m_heapVector;

public :

    ~Heap();

    int parent(int i) const {return i / 2;}
    int left(int i) const {return 2 * i;}
    int right(int i) const {return 2 * i + 1;}
    void heapify(int index);
    Node<T>* extractMin ();
    void heapDecreaseKey (int index, Node<T>* key);
    void MinHeapInsert (Node<T>* key);
    Node<T>* ExtractNode(int index);
    Node<T>* top ()const {return m_heapVector[0];}

};  

template<class T>
Heap<T>::~Heap()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < m_heapVector.size() ; i++)
        m_heapVector.erase(m_heapVector.begin() + i);
}
```

and this is the object that holds the template, I'm having problems with that also:

```
class Garage
{
    private :

        Consortium<string, Vehicle*> m_consortium;

    public :

        ~Garage() {delete &m_consortium;}
};
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: No error, a lot of memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong on its face:

```
delete &m_consortiumHeap;
```

You must only `delete` things that you allocated with `new`. `m_consortiumHeap` is part of the class and gets automatically allocated when the class gets allocated and automatically deallocated when the class gets deallocated. You cannot and must not explicitly `delete` it.

This may have the opposite problem:

```
m_consortiumMap.clear();
```

the *contents of* `m_consortiumMap` are pointers. I can't tell from the code you've shown, but if the nodes within the map are allocated by the `Consortium` class using `new`, they must be `delete`ed, otherwise you will leak memory. Clearing the map will only get rid of the pointers, it will not deallocate the memory that they point to. You must first iterate through the map and `delete` each element. While deallocation of the elements is important, clearing the map in the destructor is kind of pointless since the map itself will be destroyed immediately afterwards anyway.

This is just perplexing:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < m_heapVector.size() ; i++)
    m_heapVector.erase(m_heapVector.begin() + i);
```

first of all, everything I said about `m_consortiumMap` applies also to `m_heapVector`: If the contents were allocated with `new` by the `Heap` class, you must `delete` them in the destructor. And erasing the pointers from the vector is pointless, not to mention that the above loop has a logic error in it. When you iterate over a container, you should use the iterators themselves, e.g.

```
for (std::vector<Node<T>*>::iterator i = m_heapVector.begin() ; i != m_heapVector.end() ; i++)
```

Also, `std::vector`, like `std::map`, has a `clear()` function, but like I said it's pointless to clear the vector in the destructor. What you really want to do is deallocate the elements (if necessary).

Comment: when i tried to use the vector iterator i got : vector iterator is not incrementable, that's why i used it like this. what's the right way to do it?

Comment: @Roy can you post exactly the error you received and tell us which compiler you're using? You absolutely can increment iterators, otherwise they'd be fairly useless.

Comment: yeah i asked it in a different question and got some good answers, here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779227/why-is-this-vector-iterator-not-incrementable thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't use `new` to create an object you can't use `delete` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to delete the objects pointed by the elements in the vector. Erase method doesn't do that, it just remove the pointer element from the vector, without destroying the pointed object. So you need (I presume) to delete the pointed object first, to avoid memory leaks. You cold do this:

```
for( vector<Node<T>*>::iterator iter = m_heapVector.begin(), endI = m_heapVector.end(); iter != endI; ++iter)
{
   delete *iter;
}

// m_heapVector.clean(); // Not necessary in destructor, since the vector will be destroyed anyway.
```

Using C++0x functions:

```
std::for_each( m_heapVector.begin(), m_heapVector.end(), []( Node<T>* node) { delete node; });
```

Also, use `clear()` method of the container (vector in your case) to remove all the elements.

Comment: Or, if Boost is available, use a `ptr_vector`. Also, the same has to be done for `m_consortiumMap`, or he will have a memory leak.

Comment: Right. Still, I prefer the new future standard support for lambda functions... Much shorter, less dependencies :)

Answer (score 0):

Since m_consortiumHeap is a data member of your class (directly, not a pointer to it), you don't have to explicitly delete it.  When the Consortium instance is destructed, it will automatically call the destructor of m_consortiumHeap for you.