# Why is this vector iterator not incrementable?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, iterator

I'm trying to delete the vector's content and I'm getting an error - vector iterator is not incrementable, why is that?

This is my destructor:

```
City::~City()
{
    vector <Base*>::iterator deleteIterator;
    for (deleteIterator = m_basesVector.begin() ; deleteIterator != m_basesVector.end() ; deleteIterator++)
        m_basesVector.erase(deleteIterator);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Assuming `m_basesVector` is a member of `City`, there's no need to erase its elements; its destructor is about to do that for you.

Comment: You are aware that this will not delete the objects your pointers point to. You would have to call `delete deleteIterator;` to achieve that (if that is what you want). However, tn that case, you should prefer `boost::ptr_vector`.

Comment: See [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307082/).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`erase` invalidates the iterator. You can't use it any more. Luckily for you, it returns an iterator that you can use:

```
vector <Base*>::iterator deleteIterator = m_basesVector.begin();
while (deleteIterator != m_basesVector.end()) {
    deleteIterator = m_basesVector.erase(deleteIterator);
}
```

Or:

```
m_basesVector.clear();
```

Are you responsible for freeing the memory referred to by the pointers in the vector? If that's the reason that you're iterating (and your real program has more code that you haven't shown, that frees those objects in the loop), then bear in mind that erasing from the beginning of a vector is a slow operation, because at each step, all the elements of the vector have to be shifted down one place. Better would be to loop over the vector freeing everything (then `clear()` the vector, although as Mike says that's not necessary if the vector is a member of an object that's being destroyed).

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you are trying to use an iterator while using the erase() function. erase(), push_back(), insert(), and other modifying functions invalidate iterators in STL.

Just use the clear() function:

```
City::~City()
{
    m_basesVector.clear();
}
```

Comment: Well, whether they invalidate iterators depends on the container type.

Comment: @Matt, it doesn't depend when using vectors.

Comment: @Matt: `erase` will always invalidate iterators that refer to the erased element.

Comment: The other potential problem is that using clear() won't delete the pointers before removing them from the vector if that is necessary.

Comment: @Matt: neither will `erase()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to free the data in the vector, do this:

```
for (std::vector<Base*>::iterator it = v.begin(), e = b.end(); it != e; ++it) 
    delete *it;
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting this just incase anyone else has this this problem and attempts this solution wondering why it's not working here's an actual solution/explanation.

@Steve Jessop - Your code is flawed and you've also got it written here... ( I've also edited his post to fix the issue as soon as it's approved it'll be fixed in the original post )

http://techsoftcomputing.com/faq/3779252.html

I don't see how this is a "Solution" to the issue when it create an new issue by making an endless loop there should be a deleteIterator++ within the while loop so that it actually reaches the end of the vector.

Also I've ran into this problem and my solution was inside the while loop checking whether the iterator was equal to the end or if the vector size was 0 and breaking before attempting to incrementing the iterator.

Ex.

```
    std::vector<RankPlayer*>::iterator Rank_IT = CurrentPlayers.begin();

    while ( Rank_IT != CurrentPlayers.end() ) 
    {    
        RankPlayer* SelPlayer = (*Rank_IT);

        if( strstr( SelPlayer->GamerTag, this->GamerTag ) != NULL )
        {

            delete[] SelPlayer->PlayerData;
            delete[] SelPlayer;
            Rank_IT = CurrentPlayers.erase( Rank_IT );
        }

        if( Rank_IT == CurrentPlayers.end() || CurrentPlayers.size() == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }
            ++Rank_IT;
    }
```

Comment: This is an answer and a rant, as well as a comment. I strongly suggest making it less of a rant and comment, or it will be quickly removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not relevant to the original problem posted above, but Google search on the error takes me to this page so I am posting it here for anyone to see.

I ran into this error message recently and all lines of codes checked out (there was no 'erase' or anything alike; the vector was merely read).

Eventually, I realized that there is a problem with nested loops.

For example, consider something like this:

```
`for (it=begin(); it!=end();i++)
{
    for (; it!=end();i++)
    {
    }
}`
```

When you are done with the nested loop, it will increment the iterator - and then, the parent loop will increment it again(!), ultimately making the iterator step over the end(). I.e. it would be "end()+1" if there were such a thing.
Consequently, the parent loop throws this error at the next check.

To get around this, I ended up insert this line after the child loop:

```
`if (it == vStringList.end()) --it;`
```

Dirty, but works :D

I know it may be obvious to some, but I've been scratching my head over this for a while, lol

Answer (score 1):

Any iterator pointing to the deleted element or to the elements after the one that is deleted gets invalidated when the vector's erase method is called. Erase method returns a valid iterator pointing to the next element in the vector. You should use that iterator to continue your looping & not increment the invalidated iterator. You may also use the clear method to remove all the elements in the vector. However, you will need to remember to explicitly de-allocate any allocated memory for the elements.

Answer (score 1):

This code leaks all the contents of the vector - you have to `delete *deleteIterator` in the loop too.  You can avoid all of this by using `Base` instead of `Base*` as the `vector` contents, then `clear()` will destruct them for you.  Or use `boost::ptr_vector` which automates destruction if you do need raw pointers.

Calling `erase()` in a forward iteration like this can be very costly if the `vector` is large, as every element above the current position has to be moved down to ensure elements remain contiguous.  Avoid manual erase of the type you propose, for this and other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Vector iterators are incrementable, but if you delete elements, the vector contents are modified and thus the iterator is invalid.

So, if you delete objects, you should use the return value of `erase()` that gives you the next valid iterator.