# "Vector iterator not incrementable", Populating a vector at multiple indexes.

Tags: c++, vector

Just ran into this error, "Vector iterator not incrementable", while trying to populate a char vector using a for loop. The loop is supposed to check the first vector for where each correct letter is indexed then it is too populate the second vector with the letter at the same index accordingly. Is something in the loop causing this error?

```
    for (filler = word.begin(); filler != word.end(); filler++)
    {
        if (*filler == letter)
            guess.insert(filler, letter);
    }
```

Comment: You can't use one vector's iterator for another's functions. Just use `std::copy_if`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779227/why-is-this-vector-iterator-not-incrementable

Comment: @chris I'm not familiar with copy_if. After reading about I tried "copy_if(word.begin(), word.end(), guess.begin(), letter);" but that lead to another error C2064. Getting closer?

Comment: @user2734876, You need a predicate function.

Comment: @chris So something to check if the 'letter' and the iterator reference are the same? Ok lemme take a crack at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

filler is an iterator into the vector "word."  It cannot be used as the first argument of an insert into guess, because filter does not point into guess.

If you want it to appear at the same index, you could reconstruct the index with  filler - word.begin().  You could then use that to index into guess

```
for (filler = word.begin(); filler != word.end(); filler++)
{
    if (*filler == letter)
        guess.insert(guess.begin() + (filler - word.begin()), letter);
}
```